# Monitor if foreground app is running or just start it every minute?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a foreground app that plays videos and should keep running indefinitely in the foreground.

I made a monitoring app that has a broadcast receiver that is called by alarmmanager every minute, I was going to make the receiver onreceive check if my app is running and start it if not running, but I have made it just launch the app every minute.

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

My app is set in its manifest as

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

What is a better way?, I am thinking that launching it every minute is more reliable and uses less resources and I see no problems after running my app for a day.

pls no talk of batteries... Android does not just run on phones